# How to upload a file to 3rd API service using ASP.NET MVC 5 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-5, webclient, httppostedfilebase

I have an asp.net mvc 5 based app. One of my methods allow the user to upload file via an html-form.

When the user post the file the the framework binds binds the form-data to a view-model called `UploadFileViewModel`. The `UploadFileViewModel` has a property called `UploadedFile` with the type `HttpPostedFileBase` which gives me the info about the upload file. Typically, I would use the `SaveAs()` method on the `HttpPostedFileBase` class to save the temp file into a permanent place on the server.

However, in this case, I don't want to save the file to the server, instead I need to call a 3rd party API to store the file. The API, expects 3 parameters

1. file (type file)
2. title (type string)
3. recordType (type string)

How can I use the `WebClient` class to upload the `HttpPostedFileBase` object along with the `title`, and `recordType` parameters to the API?

The `WebClient` class has a method called `UploadFile` which accepts uri (string) and a fileName (string) How can I use this method to make the call to the remote API?

Comment: Can you provide example codes for corresponding parts explained in your question (e.g. `UploadFileViewModel` & `WebClient` class)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the HttpClient class

```
 public async Task UploadAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://hello.net/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Images/testing.png"));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "testing.png" };
        content.Add(fileContent);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/SaveFile?title=hello&recordType=audio", content);
        .....
        ....
    }
}
```